# How to remove registering and make only sysadmin add users in ckan?

Tags: python, ckan

I am trying to do some changes in my ckan plugin but I cant seem to get a hold of the signed in user sysadmin role, I am trying to do it with Jinja2 using:

`{% if user and if user_roles == "admin" %}`

And this works, but I am trying to make this only an option for sysadmins, not organization level admins, so naturally I am doing:

`{% if user_roles == "sysadmin" %}`

but it throws an error, apparently sysadmin is not in user_roles I guess. How can I get a hold of the sysadmin role ? Or is this even the right way to do it ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `check_access` to see if the logged-in user is a sysadmin as:

```
  {% set user_is_sysadmin = h.check_access('sysadmin') %}
```

Also, you will need to disable creating users from API by adding the

```
ckan.auth.create_user_via_api = False
```

To the configuration file. Read more [here](https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.9/maintaining/configuration.html#ckan-auth-create-user-via-api)